# Does JCommander Support Dynamic Params With No Prefixes?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, jcommander

I am trying to port a CLI to use [JCommander](https://jcommander.org/) but my application allows for custom parameters to be passed on the command line like this:

```
 ./App.sh -u myusername -customparam1 customval1
```

In that case `customparam1` is the name of the custom parameter and `customval1` is its value. The user can pass an arbitrary number of such parameters and the names can be anything, e.g. `customparam2`, etc.

Is JCommander capable of parsing those type of parameters? I tried using [Dynamic Parameters](https://jcommander.org/#_dynamic_parameters) but there were two problems:

- they appear to require a prefix before the parameter name, e.g. `-Dcustomparam1`, where `D` is the prefix
- they require an assignment character such as `=` between the name and the value, and space will not work as the assignment character

Any suggestions about how to use JCommander for parsing these params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an undocumented configuration option `acceptUnknownOptions` that can used like so:

```
JCommander jc = JCommander.newBuilder().addObject(app).acceptUnknownOptions(true).build();
...
List<String> unknowns = jc.getUnknownOptions();
```